# a void function that receives a template <class T> , inside a singleton class

Tags: function, templates, vector

I'm having difficulty with a function. basically I have 3 different "student" classes (this is a project simulating a college students and courses database)
bsc_student ,masters_student , other student.
I have created a singleton class called hit, inside of it is a *student vector, *course vector, this is how it looks class hit_database

```
{ public:
static hit_database* getinstance();
vector <student*> GetStudentsArray() const;
template <class T>
void instert_student_to_student_vector(T*);`

protected:
vector <course*> student_course_list;
vector <student*> students_list;
vector <student_course_connection> student_course_connector;
static hit_database* instance;
hit_database();
};`
```

as you can see I need a set function which I have made like this:

```
void hit_database::insert_student_to_student_vector(T* f)
```

{
    `this->students_list.push_back(f);
}`

now i have another class called admin_interface, inside of it there is a function create_new_student who looks like this:

```
void admin_interface::create_new_student(int id,string firstname,string lastname,string
adress,string born,int degreetype)
    {
  hit_database *hit=hit_database::getinstance();
  if (degreegtype==1)
    {
    bsc_student x(id, firstname, lastname, adress,born);
    bsc_student *created_student=&x;
    hit->insert_student_to_student_vector(created_student);
    }

if(degreegtype==2)
{
    masters_student x(id, firstname, lastname, adress,born);
    masters_student *created_student=&x;
    hit->insert_student_to_student_vector(created_student);
}
if (degreegtype==3)
{
    other_student x(id, firstname, lastname, adress,born);
    other_student *created_student=&x;
    hit->insert_student_to_student_vector<other_student>(created_student);
}
}
```

for some reason this does not work, no syntax errors, include all header, this only gets an error while trying to debug, what could it be? I've also tried template `<typename T>`,
when i changed the function so it gets only bsc_student for example, everything worked fine, I hope I explained everything, I didn't want to overload the question with including all of my files, because they are alot.

this is the error I get:

Error2 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall   hit         hit_database::instert_student_to_ student_vector(class bsc_student *)"    (??$instert_student_to_student_vector@Vbsc_student@@@hit_database@@QAEXPAVbsc_student@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall admin_interface::create_new_student(int,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >,int)" (?create_new_student@admin_interface@@QAEXHV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@000H@Z) C:\Users\Max\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\student_project\student_project\admin_interface.obj

Comment: how did your derived class inherit the base class.. (public, private, protected... unspecified?)

Comment: Spelling mistake?  instert != insert

Comment: yes spelling mistake . the hit class does not inherit , its stand alone , only includes student and course class , the admin_interface class inherits from user interface class , with public inheritence , but includes the bsc,masters,other student headers.